# Synonimize [git-index] and [git-stage]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

I propose that we synonimize [git-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-index) and [git-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stage). The meaning is absolutely the same:

> The staging area is a file, generally contained in your Git directory, that stores information about what will go into your next commit. It’s sometimes referred to as the “index”, but it’s also common to refer to it as the staging area. (from [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics))

In my opinion the best option for a main tag is [git-staging-area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-staging-area) because it's unambiguous, it certailny means the concept.

Unlike it, the words `index` and `stage` can be understood as verbs and as git commands (which is true for most git-related tags, like [git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-commit) or [git-add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-add)). It's not created yet, so maybe [git-stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-stage) could be renamed?

I'm also going to write a tag wiki for one of them. Will it survive if the descripted tag becomes a secondary synonym?

Comment: Definitely synonymise, but I say "no staging area". 39 git stage vs 49 git index - one can see that index is more popular.